# if result == 'no' - Invalid syntax

Tags: python

This is my quiz... I am sort of new to python and I am perplexed with this one. At the end, there is a {if result == 'no'} and when I run an error comes you with 'invalid syntax'. I hope it's not a stupid mistake but I'm really confused

```
print('What is your name?')
user_name = input('Name: ')
print()

print('Question 1')
age = input('How old are you ' + user_name + '? ')
print()

print('Question 2')
colour = input("What's your favourite colour " + user_name + '?')
print()

print('Question 3')
town = input('What town do you live in ' + user_name + '?')
print()

print('Question 4')
result = input('Do you want to see your results ' + user_name + '? (yes / no)')
print()

if result == 'yes':
    print('Age: ' + age + '\nFavourite Colour: ' + colour + '\nTown of residency: ' + town
          
if result == 'no':
    print('What ever')
    print('Age: ' + age + '\nFavourite Colour: ' + colour + '\nTown of residency: ' + town)
```

Comment: Did you know that closing parentheses are necessary?

Comment: Previous line. Parentheses.

Comment: Thank you to everyone how commented - abccd “sorry I did know about parentheses, but I just missed it after lots of looking!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print('Age: ' + age + '\nFavourite Colour: ' + colour + '\nTown of residency: ' + town
```

You forgot the closing `)`

Comment: Thank you I totally missed that!! If I could I would vote you up!